# Propel is dropping database column instead of just renaming it

Tags: migration, field, rename, propel

I'm looking for some help with propel's migrations feature.

Its dropping field and creating another one with the new name if the field has been renamed in schema.xml.

Buy this leads to data loss for the specified column... how can i prevent propel from doing that ?

My test case was the following :

- Creating a field in schema.xml called "title"
- Inserting data in database
- Renaming field "title" to "name"
- Issuing a select from database.

The data previously inserted in "title" field is now empty.

When looking to migration class it contains :

```
ALTER TABLE `city`

  ADD
(
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
),

  DROP `name`;
```

Answer (score 3):

When you change the column name in the XML, Propel (nor any other tool) has no way of knowing that you have renamed that column, or if you wanted to remove the old column and add the new one.

It diffs the XML with the database, and sees a column in the database which doesn't exist in your XML (title), so it deletes that column. Then it sees a column in the XML which doesn't exist in the database (name) so it creates the column title for you.

If you want to rename the column, you should do that manually.

Comment: And then reverse engineer my db ?
The thing is that the phpName does not change, propel could rely on this to detect column renaming...

Comment: The phpName isn't stored in the database though. The diff functionality doesn't diff the old and new XMLs, it diffs between the XML and the current database. You can use your diff with any database, really, if you have multiple deployments.

I agree it would be useful, but it comes with its own set of challenges to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question but the simple way to fix this is to rename the column in the xml and then generate the diff.  After that go in to the generated-migration and modify it to rename the column instead of dropping and adding it.  Then when you run the migration it will work properly.

If your database engine is MySQL the code is as follows

ALTER TABLE "table_name"
Change "column 1" "column 2" ["Data Type"];

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp